# SQL SERVER generating row number based on criteria

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table which has columns UserID,DIFFTIME. when I select these columns from the table, I also want to have a derived column which is : If the DiffTime is > 20 I want to increment the count per user id.

For example if the table has:

```
User ID DIFF TIME
 1        0
 1        5
 1        10
 2        0
 2        21
 2        5
```

I want a result set that is something like this:

```
User ID DIFF TIME SESSION NUMBER
     1        0        1
     1        5        1
     1        10       1
     2        0        1
     2        21       2
     2        5        2
```

How do I accomplish this.

Ideas and suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: Are these the only two columns in the table? I suspect you'll need something else to dictate ordering. A query can't tell that 0 happens before 5 and 5 happens before 10. Also is the 21 in your expected output a typo?

Comment: @Aaron: the other column I have is eventTime..Nope 21 is not a typo...if the difftime is greater than 20 then increment the count.

Comment: 21 represents a count? In the original data, doesn't 20 represent a time? Do you want to increment the session number, or the time? I'm clearly lost here.

Comment: @Aaron: If the diff time is > 20 increment the count of the session number. Hope I have made myself clear.

Comment: You still need to explain. The original table has 20 in the 5th row. The output has 21. Did you mean to increment both the time and the session number? Did you mean to have 21 in the original table?

Comment: @Aaron: Sorry I missed your point earlier. I meant to have 21 in the original table.

Comment: Wow, what a lot of wasted time. Now, perhaps you should go revisit some of the ***58*** questions you've asked, and up-vote one or two of the answers? It's not possible that you've accepted more than half of the answers (still not a good ratio) but didn't find a ***single*** answer helpful or otherwise worthy of an up-vote. This site is full of volunteers trying to help you, the least you can do is reward them with your up-votes (which cost you nothing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table #t
(
 id int,
 Diff int,
 SessionNumber int
)
insert into #t(id, diff)values(1, 0)
insert into #t(id, diff)values(1, 5)
insert into #t(id, diff)values(1, 10)
insert into #t(id, diff)values(2, 0)
insert into #t(id, diff)values(2, 21)
insert into #t(id, diff)values(2, 5)


Select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by Id) as RowID, * into #Temp1 from #t 
Declare @diff int
Declare @RowId int
Declare @Previous int
Declare @NewValue int

DECLARE @Cur CURSOR SET @Cur = CURSOR FOR select RowId, diff from #Temp1
OPEN @Cur
FETCH NEXT FROM @Cur INTO @RowId, @diff
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    if(@RowId = 1)
    Begin
        Update #Temp1 Set SessionNumber = 1 Where rowid = 1     
        Set @Previous = @Diff
        Set @NewValue = 1
    End
    Else
    Begin
        if(@Diff - @Previous > 20)
        Begin
            Set @Previous = @Diff
            Set @NewValue = @NewValue + 1
            Update #Temp1 Set SessionNumber = @NewValue Where rowid = @RowId
        End
        else
            Update #Temp1 Set SessionNumber = @NewValue Where rowid = @RowId

    End
    FETCH NEXT FROM @Cur INTO @RowId, @diff
END
CLOSE @Cur
DEALLOCATE @Cur

select * from #temp1

drop table #t
drop table #temp1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this statement:

```
select t1.User_Id, t1.Diff_Time, 
    isnull(count(t2.User_Id), 0) + 1 as Session_Number
from @table t1
left join @table t2 
    on t1.User_Id = t2.User_Id 
    and t1.eventTime >= t2.eventTime 
    and t2.Diff_Time > 20
group by t1.User_Id, t1.Diff_Time, t1.eventTime
order by t1.User_Id, t1.eventTime
```

(replace `@table` with your actual table name)

***Note:** I assume that the fifth row of your table has the value 21 in the `Diff_Time` column, and there's a typo in the question, as @AaronBertrand pointed out in the comments*

Comment: @AaronBertrand I assumed that's a typo, as you pointed out. I tested this on a table that has the value `21` in the fifth row.

Comment: The OP just commented that the 20 in the first table is a typo and it should have been 21. As far as I can tell this gives the correct results.